# Ambiguity in Rounding of Significant Figures

Tags: error-analysis

This is not a direct physics question, but I guess quite related. Given a number stated in five significant figures (5 SFs)
**x=3.1449**, what's the corresponding rounded value in 2 SFs?

I would (of course) say it is **x=3.1**, however if the rounding is performed insteps like: 1-) round from 5 to 4 SFs x=3.145 , 2-) re-round from 4 to 3 SFs x=3.15, 3-) finally round from 3 to 2 SFs it's now **x=3.2** ...

What's wrong here? Are we not allowed to perform step by step rounding?

Comment: There is no way to prevent rounding errors due to multi step rounding, eg. 4.44+4.44 if rounded step by step becomes 4.4+4.4=8.8, while if rounded at the final step becomes 4.44+4.44=8.88 = 8.9. Generally we try to round at the last possible moment, and overpower our precision if possible, so that rounding errors can't hurt the conclusion.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, afaiu then the *ambiguity* in the final result (due to multi-step rounding) is a natural (and unavoidable) condition...

Comment: yes in continuous measurements, like length mark on a ruler, we can't ever be sure if 2.0 means 2.0000000 or 2.0000001, because the ruler is not that precise. *unless* we quantize everything and disallow these too small variations. trying to run a continuous universe will lead to all sorts of errors in the long run. (is it just a coincidence that everything seems quantized at the very smallest scale?)

Comment: If all of your measurement devices can report 5 significant figures, you need to give your answer in 5 significant figures rather than rounding to 2 significant figures.

Comment: I just remembered the root cause of the inconsistency; rounding is, of course, a **nonlinear** mathematical process, and as such **superposition** won't hold in general: distributed steps of rounding will not produce same result of a single step equivalent rounding application... Though in practice it will yield a consistent result more often than not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are we not allowed to perform step by step rounding?

You are not allowed to perform step by step rounding. Furthermore, for calculations, the intermediate steps should retain enough extra digits to not affect the final rounded result. Rounding to significant figures is done at the end.

By the way, significant figures is just “training wheels” for students. As such, we expect them to wobble and break as it were. In professional scientific publications you actually state the uncertainty explicitly. You never leave it implied by the use of significant figures.

Comment: Thanks for the answer which I was possibly expecting, yet could not find a source to verify... Do you know where it is stated that we are not allowed to perform multi step rounding, even at the end of computation?

Comment: @Fat32 yes. The best source of information for how to handle uncertainty is the BIPM (the people that make the SI system) publication "Guide to the Expression of Uncertainty in Measurement" ( https://www.bipm.org/documents/20126/2071204/JCGM_100_2008_E.pdf/cb0ef43f-baa5-11cf-3f85-4dcd86f77bd6 ). Be warned, this is the no-training-wheels version of uncertainty. See Section 4.4.3, Section 7.2.6, and Appendix H.0,

Comment: Well thanks for the link. Actually we (electrical & electronics engineers) deal with *measurement and instrumentation* quite professionally (though I'm not from that branch). I was just curious about the concept of *significant figures* in physics, which seems as you stated to be a training wheels for undergraduates...